# Create dataset in wso2 ML by integration with wso2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-ml

I want create a new dataset in wso2 ML with source type equal DAS. I am runing ML in https://localhost:9444 and DAS in https://localhost:9445. When I select DAS as source type, I dont get data from DAS. In Das I have three tables. View image.

[image]

I reviewed this documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML100/Integration+with+WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server and verified analytics-datasource.xml in DAS and ML where ANALYTICS_FS_DB, ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE and ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE have the same configuration in the two systems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide paths to WSO2 DAS datasources as URLs in `<ML_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/analytics-datasources.xml` file for given DBs.

e.g. For `WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB` the value of `<url>` element should look like below,

```
<url>jdbc:h2:/home/user/wso2das-3.0.0/repository/database/ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
```